# Python: Cannot debug using vs code using virtual environment

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

I set up a python virtual environment named "myenv" in my project. Then, I try to debug the script from VS code.

Here is the output. Please give some insights. Thanks

```
    $ cd d:\\xx\\yy ; env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 d:\\xx\\yy\\myenv\\Scripts\\python.exe c:\\Users\\xyz\\.v
scode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\\pythonFiles\\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 1817 d:\\xx\
\yy\\.vscode\\launch.json
bash: env: command not found
(myenv)
```

My launch json looks like below.

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The problem is solved after installing the latest version VS code.

Answer (score 0):

If you install and use [Python Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) from Microsoft then you can just start VS Code from your project root folder: `code .` Then open some Python source file and in the lower left corner at the bottom status bar of VS Code you will see your current Python execution environment. You can click and change it by selecting your environment from the list.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Although I have done the steps described, the debugging is not working.

Comment: Are you able to change your (virtual) Python environment from the status bar in this extension? Does it show your default Python env?

Comment: yes. If I use the global python interpreter, the debugger can work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are running under Windows but you set your shell to bash. If you're using WSL then please see the [instructions on remote development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) which includes WSL. If you're using git-bash then please note the Python extension does not support git-bash as a shell.

Comment: The problem is solved when I install the latest version VS code.